# Is there anyway to submit iMessage extension to AppStore

Tags: ios, app-store, imessage

I want to upload an extension without app to the iOS AppStore. While running debug, device can run extension and I see no app installed. However, I don't know Apple allows to upload extension without app to the iOS AppStore or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can submit iMessage apps without an iOS app. However, you mentioned that your iMessage app as extension, which needs to be uploaded with your iOS app.

According to [iMessage App Submissions](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/imessage-app-submissions/), you can submit an iMessage app or Sticker Pack to the App Store without an app. If you did build your iMessage app as extension of your iOS app, you need to submit within your app.

I hope the following links can help:

[Submitting an iMessage app - part 1](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/tutorials/itc-stickers-part1/)

[Submitting an iMessage app - part 2](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/tutorials/itc-stickers-part2/)